# Trying to convert time stored in char to normal form. Printing a random value. Whats wrong?

Tags: c++, time

Here is a short code I have written to print time entered as string or char to hh:mm:ss form.
No compilation errors but gives a garbage value. Whats wrong with it?
**Note : I don't want to print the day/month/year thing.**

```
# include<iostream>
# include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){

        const char *time_details = "15:34:12";
        struct tm tm;
        strptime(time_details, "%H:%M:%S", &tm);
        time_t t = mktime(&tm);
        cout << t  << endl;


}
```

Comment: Looks right to me. That prints the underlying timestamp that represents that time. Normally this is the number of seconds since midnight 1st January 1970. Off the top of my head I can't remember what day/month/year gets filled in by default here.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page on `strptime`:

> If the format string does not contain enough conversion specifications to completely specify the resulting struct tm, the unspecified members of tm are left untouched.

You need to either set those other members, or only use the ones that you did set.

**Update**
Another problem here is the use of `mktime`. From the OpenGroup description of that function,

> If the time since the Epoch cannot be represented, the function shall return the value (time_t)-1

If you simply zero-out the structure `tm` you will be creating a time that cannot be represented in Unix time format (seconds since 00Z, January 1, 1970). At a minimum, you need to set the year and day of month to non-zero values.